# Получение ответа с сервера. Как обработать каждый ответ отдельно?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Я вот не понимаю как отправляя схожие запросы, но с разными параметрами, получая все ответы в один и тот же коллбек потом организовать к какому запросу какой ответ пришел? Может сам такой подход в корне не правильный? Но как тогда сделать?

Еще хотелось бы таймаут сделать, что если в течении минуты не было ответа, сделать еще три попытки, и если все неудачны то "сдаться" отписавшись в console.log и продолжить работать дальше.

Например есть форум, у которого надо получить информацию об определенных пользователях по id:

```js
var https = require("https");

users = [{
  id: 5
}, {
  id: 16
}, {
  id: 30
}, {
  id: 7
}, {
  id: 1085
}, {
  id: 800
}, ];

for (var cUser in users) {

  https.get("example.com/api/users?id=" + users[cUser].id, function(resp) {

    resp.setEncoding('utf8');

    var str = '';
    resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
      str += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', () => {
      var recieved = JSON.parse(str);
      for (var attr in recieved) {
        users[cUser][attr] = recieved[attr];
      }

      /*  Я так понимаю, что это выполняется как только пришел ответ,
       *   поэтому значение cUser уже изменилось. Но как его сохранить?
       *   _________________________________________________________________
       *
       *   Что примерно присылает сервер:
       *   {id:1,joined:1219448281,status:0,raiting:90000,postcount:136}
       */

    });
  });
}


/*   Ожидания:                |   Реальность:
 *                            |
 *   >console.log(users);     |   >console.log(users);
 *                            |
 *   [                        |   [
 *     {                      |     {id: 5},
 *       id: 5,               |     {id: 16},
 *       joined: 1219449600,  |     {id: 30},
 *       status: 2,           |     {id: 7},
 *       raiting: 35245,      |     {id: 1085},
 *       postcount: 2304      |     {id: 800},
 *     },                     |   ];
 *     {                      |
 *       id: 16,              |
 *       joined: 1234569405,  |
 *       status: 4,           |
 *       raiting: 1023,       |
 *       postcount: 176       |
 *     },                     |
 *     ... и так далее        |
 *   ];                       |
 */
```

Я в Node.JS не профессионал, а только начинающий. Очень приветвуется ответ с кодом и его пояснением. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте заменить var на let в первом цикле for, тогда каждый cUser будет объявлен на уровне блока for { .. }.